# Room Android - Array of float, integer, double,.... - You can consider adding a type converter for it

Tags: android, arrays, android-room

I'm just begin with Room-Android.

I try to persist one of my model which one of the fields is an array:

```
float[] values;
```

I got this error at the compilation:

```
Error: Cannot figure out how to save this field into database. 
You can consider adding a type converter for it.
```

I created a type converter:

```
public static class ConverterFloatToString {

    @TypeConverter
    public String JSONArrayfromFloatArray(Float[] values) {
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(Arrays.asList(values));
        return jsonArray.toString();
    }

    @TypeConverter
    public float[] JSONArrayToFloatArray(String values) {
        try {
            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(values);
            float[] floatArray = new float[jsonArray.length()];
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                floatArray[i] = Float.parseFloat(jsonArray.getString(i));
            }
            return floatArray;
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

and i assigned to the field:

```
@TypeConverters(ConverterFloatToString.class)
float[] values;
```

But i still get the same error.

```
Cannot figure out how to save this field into database. 
You can consider adding a type converter for it.
```

What is wrong please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok i made a mistake in my type converter.

```
JSONArrayfromFloatArray(Float[] values) -> JSONArrayfromFloatArray(float[] values)
```

And i changed my converter to this:

```
public static class ConverterFloatToString {

    @TypeConverter
    public static String JSONArrayfromFloatArray(float[] values) {
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
        for (float value : values) {
            try {
                jsonArray.put(value);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return jsonArray.toString();
    }

    @TypeConverter
    public static float[] JSONArrayToFloatArray(String values) {
        try {
            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(values);
            float[] floatArray = new float[jsonArray.length()];
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                floatArray[i] = Float.parseFloat(jsonArray.getString(i));
            }
            return floatArray;
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

But i'm not fan of this solution, with these conversions an error could happen... If you have better solution i take it ;)